# RecyclerView dependency causing Floating Action Button null pointer

Tags: android

I've got a Floating Action Button within my app, which is working fine with no errors.
When I add a dependency to the gradle for just the latest version of RecyclerView, it causes a null pointer on the floating action button.

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
```

This is the dependency for the support design library

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

Has anyone else had a similar issue?

Seems strange that including the recyclerview dependency is breaking the floatingactionbutton!

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Your support libraries are of different versions: 23.3.0 and 23.1.1

Comment: That has fixed it, would it be worthwhile you answering the question for anyone else who might have this same (simple) issue due to differing versions, specifically one that is a component of the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your support libraries are of different versions - they need to be the same version for it to work well.

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
```